# Permanently disable security system

Tags: security

We moved house about a year ago. The previous owner had an alarm system, which we assumed was inactive, but whenever we lose/regain power, the panels beep intermittently.

We've somehow armed the system though, and now the alarm goes off whenever we enter the house. We don't have a code, so we have to turn the mains off, which stops the alarm but leaves it armed.

Is there a way to permanently disable the system? Here are some pics of the panels and what I believe is the control panel.

Thanks in advance.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Find the incoming AC power feed. Disconnect and cap off. Remove the battery connections (the black thing in the lower left of the panel. No more power to the system.

Comment: I have to ask: why haven't you called the phone number on the label inside the control panel?

Comment: I moved into a place with such a system installed by a previous owner and I found the manual online, and reprogrammed it for my own use. Free alarm system. You don't have to pay for monitoring if you don't want to, a siren is better than nothing.

Comment: @CatchAsCatchCan there's a chance it might still be active; I know mine wasn't when I tried - the company were no longer in business

Comment: @CatchAsCatchCan If the OP calls, the first question from the  alarm company will be “What’s your account number?”.

Comment: Why not contact the previous owner? You have nothing to lose and a lot to gain. Also check for alarm company stickers and if you find one contact them and tell they you purchased the house and need the alarm system checked etc. My thoughts if you have it use it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Disconnect the battery and the power supply (if you can find where it's plugged in, somewhere near the brown box, unplug it.) Unfortunately your picture of the label is not quite clear enough to read.

[image]

But the first two wires on the left of the power strip say 16 VAC, so that's the power supply that's plugged into the wall somewhere, and the plug to the left of them looks to be the battery.

Usually looks like this, more or less:

[image: alarm transformer image from alarmgrid.com]

If you can't find and unplug the 16 VAC transformer, cap off those wires with a wirenut and/or electrical tape. Actually likely more reliable to remove only one of them and cap it (which still shuts the system off, but reduces the odds of the two coming into contact with both loose.) But better to find and unplug it (if not found, try taking the box off the wall, it may be behind)

In most cases you can look up the alarm model number and [find out how to reset it](https://chrisschuld.com/2019/02/programming-a-dsc-alarm-1832/) (*Relevant, no affiliation*) so that you can control and use it, rather than disabling it permanently.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. The AC wires are going into a hole in the wall. If I'm not sure where they're plugged in, should I try switching off breakers until it powers off to help narrow it down?

Comment: Flipping breakers, @user123965, is the _only_ way to find out if the labeling on the panel isn't clear enough.

Comment: Typical alarm-guy hack is that those wires pop out of the wall again next to an outlet. 99% of the time, the plug in transformer there is a similar brown color to the big wall-box with the main board in it. There are other possible ways, but that's typical. And yes, as Freeman says, you'll flip breakers (and perhaps do some other labeling updates) if your labelling isn't clear.

Comment: I've narrowed it down to the microwave circuit! I still haven't found the plug, but at least I can keep that breaker off for now until I find it. If not, I'll have to try capping.

Comment: Look near the electrical panel, and look near (in any direction from, through walls, floor, ceiling etc.) the location of the alarm box.

Comment: I think walking though the house and looking for AC adapters with no known purpose would be faster than flipping breakers.  I don't see how flipping breakers will help find it.  A mysterious powered wall wart looks a lot like a mysterious unpowered one.

Comment: I don't love the "remove one wire and tape" approach.  That will leave the mystery PSU plugged in and totally useless, with its wire disappearing into the wall.   In 15 years, some poor sucker will be afraid to unplug it for fear of whatever.  The house blowing up.  People think that way.  :(  It will remain plugged in and useless forever.

Comment: If you have done a through job looking for it and not found it, (which is the first thing I suggest) what alternate approach are you suggesting? rip the walls open to follow the wire?

Comment: I get a bit obsessive with these things.  Quit your job, stop eating, find the damn thing. :)

Comment: given it went off with the microwave, i'd look at the outlet where the microwave is plugged in.  Imagining an OTR where the plug is above and in a cabinet which is a good place to put a transformer or on top of kitchen cabinets.

Comment: Next step: follow those wires connected to the right most 4 terminals, it looks like they come from a telephone wire,  unplug it from that jack I see above and make sure your phone service still works.  Older alarm systems would try to call the monitoring company.  Newer ones may have cell or internet connections.

Answer (score 31):

Per your pictures you have a DSC 1832 system and [the manual can be found here](https://cms.dsc.com/download.php?t=1&id=17007). What you might try is [doing a factory reset](https://help.aartech.ca/portal/en/kb/articles/factory-reset-dsc-pc1616-pc1832-pc1864)

> 1. Power down the system completely.
> 2. Connect a short (wire) between Zone 1 and PGM1 on the control panel (remove all other wires form these terminals).
> 3. Power up the control panel (AC power only) for 10 full seconds.
> 4. Power down the control panel, remove short between Zone 1 and PGM1.
> 5. Power up the control panel.

Once you have the system reset, the manual walks you through the process to set it up for yourself.

Answer (score 8):

You need to disconnect both AC power and battery power.

The battery is easy - remove the red and black wires from the terminals on top of the battery.

The AC is a bit trickier. AC power is coming on the left-most black and red wires on the left terminal block. They should be connected to a power adapter or transformer "somewhere". That could be a plug-in block plugged into a regular 120V AC receptacle. Or it could be a transformer mounted on a box somewhere like a doorbell transformer. Turn off the breaker for this circuit (if you do that after you disconnect the battery then the alarm will be totally off) and then trace the wires and disconnect them. Do *not* disconnect the wires from the terminal block without also disconnecting them from the AC source. Otherwise they could be dangerous for someone who doesn't know they're live (though not a huge danger because they are low voltage) and also some future person may find the transformer or power pack and not know they can remove it.

Comment: can you elaborate on the last sentence, why it matters so much..

Comment: It's a power-limited low voltage circuit. Really not that dangerous. Better to kill it at the source, yes. But dangerous - not unless you start fiddling with it as you are having a gas leak.

Comment: Disconnecting at the source is certainly better, but as long as they're properly capped, I don't think it poses much of an additional danger. Anyone in the habit of assuming wires aren't live without checking shouldn't really be doing electrical work.

Comment: @MichaelMior That's true, but there is an additional danger here. The standard NCVT is for 50V+. It won't detect these wires, so while not as dangerous as line voltage, there is a danger that might not be so obvious to the next guy.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Very good point :)

Answer (score 0):

Can I just remove contact points screwed into my threshold/under the door? No more monitoring company but it’s very loud alarm when we open that door after we lose and then regain power.  I know the code to stop it— but if I’m away and I have handyman over or one of grandkids stops in, it’s crazy.  Everyone seems uncomfortable with disarming it with the code.  I even have number taped to top of keypad box!!!

Comment: It is unclear if you are answering the question or saying me too!